# How to use GCM to achieve reliable delivery to iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set up reliable push notifications to iOS devices, and I'm looking for guidance on what a recommended approach would be using Google Cloud Messaging. My app is a messaging app but this probably applies to other types of apps.

Currently, I'm using GCM via the HTTP Connection server, and I'm finding that if the iOS device loses service or is off, not all the messages get delivered. I believe that this is the expected performance, which occurs because GCM uses Apple's APNS, which does not guarantee delivery and sadly only holds a maximum of one notification in a queue per app.

I was hoping (wishing?) that GCM would hold its own queue to solve this problem. Maybe it does, and I'm just not doing it right?

Other possibilities I've come across:

- [Non-collapsible messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages). Unfortunately, the documentation confuses me as to whether I would be able to use this to achieve what I need.
- The [delivery_receipt_requested](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref) flag. This could, at a minimum, (though adding complexity for me) be used to determine whether the message arrived. I see that it requires XMPP. But if I set the flag on a single HTTP request with multiple registration_ids, maybe I would get back multiple XMPP responses? I'm open to switching over to using XMPP. If this is the recommended path, what are some recommendations for how to implement this? ALSO, are these delivery receipts reliable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't tell wether your push notification was delivered to the iOS device unless you implement a loop back in the device. But this won't really help you either, since the device could have bad connectivity and still receive the notification but your loop back request may not go through, also your users can turn of background fetch, which will make the loop back impossible.

Therefore you won't be able to fully solve your problem - but using the loop back is your best bet to solve this problem for most users.

In the notification you have to set `content-available:1` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

And also implement following method in your AppDelegate and make an API request to your server that the message was successfully received:

```
- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:

Comment: Can this same (half baked) solution be achieved using the Google Cloud Connection Sever (XMPP) delivery_receipt_requested flag? It looks like Google recommends putting the line `[[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo]` in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` in order to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like it, but I have had just a short glimpse. Just make sure that you know that this is not 100% reliable due to the reasons I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCM to send so called Data messages. Read here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#notifications_and_data_messages

Pros is that they do not collapse by default, like you want. Cons is that GCM can only deliver them over it's own connection, not via APNS, which means that your app will receive them only while running (i.e. not in background). If it's not good enough for you, consider sending a combination of Notification messages (that always go via APNS) and Data messages.

> But if I set the flag on a single HTTP request with multiple registration_ids, maybe I would get back multiple XMPP responses?

No.

> ALSO, are these delivery receipts reliable?

They are best efforts. Which means that in some cases (like bad device connectivity) you might not receive a receipt immediately or receive duplicates. Also, delivery receipts are only supported for Data messages, not Notifications.